# Custom user levels and permissions MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to use the following method whenever the GET or POST is called to create or edit an article page:

```
' userId = ID or username of the user logged in
' companyId = ID or name of the company for which the current blog is assigned
' blogId = ID or name of the blog for which the article is being written
' returnSuccessView = the view that will be returned if the user has access
' returnFailView = the view  that will be returned if the user does not have access

return View(CheckUserAccess(userId, companyId, blogId, returnSuccessView, returnFailView))
```

Can someone show me what this function would look like?  My structure is:

> Companies -> Blogs -> Articles -> Comments

I want to create permissions so only users that belong to a certain company and belong to a certain blog and have certain permissions can perform the requested task.

For instance, my user model would have an ICollection of companies to which the user can be associated with, and they can have an ICollection of blogs they can be associated with.  They can also have an ICollection of permissions, such as super-user, article writer, article editor, moderator, etc.

I would create a separate model for permissions so that they can be added and removed via a UI.

The function should check whether or not the requested company, blog and permissions match that which the user is associated with (has in their ICollection).

What's the best way to go about something like this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you handling this with a custom `[Authorize]` attribute. Let's take an example:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!authorized)
        {
            // The user is not even authenticated => we can't get much further
            return false;
        }

        // At this stage we know that there's an authneticated user
        // let's see who he is by fecthing his username
        string username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;

        RouteData rd = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;

        // Now, let's read the companyId and blogId parameters that he sent
        // into the request and ensure that he is not cheating on us
        string companyId = rd.Values["companyId"] as string;
        string blogId = rd.Values["blogId"] as string;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(companyId) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(blogId))
        {
            // One of the required parameters were not supplied when the action was invoked
            // => we can't get much further
            return false;
        }

        return IsOwner(username, companyId, blogId);
    }

    private bool IsOwner(string username, string companyId, string blogId)
    {
        // TODO: you know what to do here: 
        // check with your data store or wherever you have stored this info
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now you could decorate your controllers/actions with this attribute:

```
[MyAuthorize]
public ActionResult Edit(string companyId, string blogId)
{
    // if we got that far it means that the user is authorized to edit this blog post
    // and we could allow him to see the edit view
    EditViewModel model = ...
    return View(model); 
}
```

And of course to ensure that the user is not trying to cheat on you on the POST action you could also decorate it with this attribute:

```
[MyAuthorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(EditViewModel model)
{
    // if we got that far it means that the user is authorized to edit this blog post
    // and we could go ahead and perform the necessary update
    ....
}
```

Comment: That was insightful.  However, I don't exactly know how to the the part for IsOwner (that's actually what I was asking in my question).  If I have an ICollection in my User model that stores all the user's associated companies, how do I check that ICollection for the company being requested?

Comment: Oh that's some database or whatever you are using specific question. This has strictly nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC 3 which is what your initial question was about. In my answer I showed you how to write a custom authorization attribute allowing you to read RouteData parameters and retrieve the currently connected username. How you would verify if an user belongs to a blog or a company or I don't know what will entirely depend on your implementation. So I would suggest you starting a new thread, explaining the data access technology you are using (EF I guess), showing your DB schema, ...

Comment: ... and asking a very specific question about how to perform a given SQL or whatever query.

Comment: I specifically mentioned ICollection in the question several times asking, "Can someone show me what this function would look like?"  Should I open a new question for this?  I don't want to create a duplicate...  I feel like I asked exactly what I meant, but still don't know how to do it.

Comment: I understand what you are saying.  I will try posting a new question specific to the entity framework that I am using, then.  Though, it would be beneficial if you could answer it here being as it is basically the same question that I am asking.

Comment: Question about your solution:  The line string companyId = rd.Values["companyId"] as string; seems to say that companyId is determined in the route.  It is not in the route, the route just looks like Blog/Edit/1, not MyCompany/Blog/Edit/1.  Am I misunderstanding you?  Thanks.

Comment: Also, your solution is in C# whereas I need one in VB.  I suppose I could try to go through and convert it, but I am here because I am not that good in VB :) So, it would be helpful to have you or someone translate it into VB.

Comment: userwhatever - you really do not want to be passing around a user object with a whole bunch of iCollections somehow attached to it.  Look it up from the db as Darin suggests, and only look it up when you need it and don't persist it.  If company isn't in your route, then just change that line to get it from whereever you store it.

Comment: I don't know where/ how to store the relationship.  I opened another question for this aspect here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722458/extend-standard-asp-net-membership-to-support-more-relations

Comment: Where does one define an authorize attribute?  Should I put it in a a separate file and then do an include?